# Edit the amount of colors available in a picture plotting program. It's written in C with Xlib

Tags: c, graphics, fortran, pixel, xlib

I'm a fortran programmer working with a program written in C (which I have Little to no experience with).

I have a program written in fortan that creates an image in the form of a multidimentional array of pixels with their X value, Y value, and RGB values (0-4 for each color). It then passes the array, the size of the array in the x and y dimensions, the color map containing all the colors arranged in a spectrum, and the number of colors in the spectrum to a program written in C that is supposed to plot the image using Xlib.

The program works when I pass a particular one color map with 125 colors (5 values for red/green/blue) but when I try to increase the amount of colors I pass to the C program I exceed some sort of limit and the program shuts down. How do I raise the limit in the C source code?

Here is the program:

```
    #define USEPIXMAP  /* sets drawing into background pixmap of window */

    #include "putras.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>
    static unsigned def_map[256];

    void putras_(int *pixel_values, int *arrayx, int *arrayy,
                int *colormap_entries, int *colormap_size)
    {
      extern Colormap       cmap;
      extern Window         window;
      extern Display        *dpy;
      extern XColor         color;
      extern XWindowAttributes  window_attr;
      extern GC             gc;
      extern XGCValues      gcv;
      extern Pixmap         pixmap;

      static int call_flag = 0;
      char           *display_name=NULL;
      char           *dummy;
      unsigned            pixel;
      int            i, j;
      XPoint         *pointarray[256];
      unsigned            arraylen[256];
      unsigned            maxlen[256];
      int            remain_len;

      if(call_flag == 0) {

        /* THis only gets done on the first call to putras */

        call_flag = 1;
        if( (dpy = XOpenDisplay(display_name) ) == NULL){
          fprintf(stderr,"Error: Couldn't open display\n");
          exit(1);
        }
        XGetWindowAttributes(dpy, RootWindow(dpy,DefaultScreen(dpy)),
                             &window_attr);
        window=XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, RootWindow(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy)), 0, 0,
                                 *arrayx, *arrayy,window_attr.border_width,
                                 BlackPixel(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy)),
                                 WhitePixel(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy)));

    #ifdef USEPIXMAP
        pixmap=XCreatePixmap(dpy, window, *arrayx, *arrayy,
                             DefaultDepth(dpy,DefaultScreen(dpy)) );
        XMapWindow(dpy, window);
        XClearWindow(dpy, window);
        XCopyArea(dpy, window, pixmap, DefaultGC(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy)),
                  0,0,*arrayx, *arrayy, 0,0);
        XFlush(dpy);
    #else
        XMapWindow(dpy, window);
    #endif

        cmap=DefaultColormap(dpy,DefaultScreen(dpy));

        color.flags=DoRed|DoBlue|DoGreen;
        for (i=0;i<(*colormap_size);i++){
          color.pixel= colormap_entries[4*i];
          j = color.pixel;
          color.red=colormap_entries[4*i+1];
          color.green=colormap_entries[4*i+2];
          color.blue=colormap_entries[4*i+3];
          XAllocColor(dpy, cmap, &color);
          def_map[j] = color.pixel;
        }

        gc = XCreateGC(dpy, window, 0, NULL);

      } /* Endif - first time through */

      /* The following gets done on each call */
      for (i=0; i<256; i++){

          pointarray[i]=(XPoint *)malloc((*arrayx)*(*arrayy)/128*sizeof(XPoint));
          maxlen[i]=(*arrayx)*(*arrayy)/128 -1;
          arraylen[i]=0;
      }
        for (j=0; j<(*arrayy); j++) {
         for (i=0; i<(*arrayx); i++) {
           /*pixel = def_map[pixel_values[j * (*arrayx) + i]];*/
           pixel=pixel_values[j*(*arrayx)+i];
           /*pixel=1;*/

            if (arraylen[pixel]==maxlen[pixel]) {
              pointarray[pixel]= (XPoint *)realloc(pointarray[pixel],
                                                   2*maxlen[pixel]*sizeof(XPoint));
              maxlen[pixel]=2*maxlen[pixel];
          }

              pointarray[pixel][arraylen[pixel]].x=i;
           pointarray[pixel][(arraylen[pixel])++].y=j;
         } /* end for loop*/
        } /* end for loop*/

      for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
        XSetForeground(dpy, gc, def_map[i]);/*dpy,gc,i);*/
         if (arraylen[i]>=MAXPOINT) { 
            for (j=0; j<=(arraylen[i]/MAXPOINT); j++) {
               remain_len=(arraylen[i]-MAXPOINT*j);
    #ifdef USEPIXMAP
               XDrawPoints(dpy, pixmap, gc,(pointarray[i]+j*MAXPOINT),
                          ((remain_len<MAXPOINT)?remain_len:MAXPOINT),
                          CoordModeOrigin);
    #else
               XDrawPoints(dpy, window, gc,(pointarray[i]+j*MAXPOINT),
                          ((remain_len<MAXPOINT)?remain_len:MAXPOINT),
                          CoordModeOrigin);
    #endif

            } /* end for loop */
         } else {

    #ifdef USEPIXMAP
             XDrawPoints(dpy, pixmap, gc, pointarray[i], arraylen[i],
                         CoordModeOrigin);
    #else
             XDrawPoints(dpy, window, gc, pointarray[i], arraylen[i],
                         CoordModeOrigin);
    #endif
          } /*  end if */
      } /* end for loop 256 */

    #ifdef USEPIXMAP
      XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap(dpy, window, pixmap);
      XClearWindow(dpy, window);
    #endif

      XFlush(dpy);
      for (i=0; i<256;i++)
        free(pointarray[i]);

      return;
    }


    void unmap(void)
    {
    /*  extern Pixmap pmap; */

      extern Window window;
      extern Display *dpy;

    /*  int width, height; */

      XUnmapWindow(dpy, window);
      XFlush(dpy);
      return;
    }

    void remap(void)
    {
      extern Window window;
      extern Display *dpy;

      XMapRaised(dpy, window);
      XFlush(dpy);
      return;
    }
```

Comment: What the program prints when it exits?

Comment: It just quits and says "Segmentation Fault"

Comment: After some checking the segmentation fault occurs when the value of colormap_size hits 256 and above

Comment: Do you know the exact line of the seg fault? `def_map[j] = color.pixel;` looks suspicious, as it is defined as only 256 long/big.

Comment: I doubled every instance of 256 in the program to 512 (and the instances of 128 to 256) and the number of colors now goes up to 511 before the segfault occurs. So I've solved my problem of more colors but now I don't know WHY it works or if I've caused an error for myself somewhere in the future. 

I also changed the unsigned variables to unsigned int to give me more space.

Comment: colormap_size must be less than the size of def_map.  The size of your colormap_entries must be 4 times that of def_map.  Where is colormap_entries initialized?  The program is getting the index j from it.

Comment: colormap_entries is passed by reference by the fortran program, the colormap_entries is basically a picture of the spectrum that the program selects colors from